# Rails devise delete/cancel user isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, devise-invitable

I apologize if asked in twice. as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788974/devise-sign-out-not-working-after-implementation-of-devise-invitable) has already been asked but not with any kind of help at all :(

So the problem part is when I am implementing the [Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)  and after successful implementation everything works flawlessly except destroy_user_registration.

```
<%= link_to user_registration_path(resource_name), method: :delete do %>
    <span class="text">Delete My Account</span>
<% end %>
```

and here is routes.rb for User part

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {
 sign_in: 'login',
 sign_out: 'logout',
 sign_up: 'register',
 password: 'reset',
 edit: 'account'
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't very helpful. What happened and what you expected?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran same problem as this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788974/devise-sign-out-not-working-after-implementation-of-devise-invitable` question but I also facing this issue on Users::RegistrationController destroy function.

Comment: @RanaAlie `rake routes | grep user` run this on project directory at console, what output it returns?

Comment: @Gabbar please have a look https://imgur.com/a/ydEU7Uj